# Webpack + Babel (ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require)

Tags: javascript, webpack, visual-studio-code, babeljs, require

after trying to install the webpack successfully, but now this is giving this error, ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require.

It has already been created or bundle.js, and it was used in index.html. Before generating this bundle.js I am simply creating a test function in another js file, and importing it into main.js, which is being placed in the bundle.js

```
import soma from './funcoes'
console.log(soma(1, 2));
```

Here bundle.js, the error is being accused in that require:

```
var _funcoes = _interopRequireDefault(require("./funcoes"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { "default": obj }; }

console.log((0, _funcoes["default"])(1, 2));
```